# How do I update my javascript code that I used on oncomplete event of PrimeFaces commandButton component

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2

I'am using Primefaces to develop my website.
I use `commandButton` component. When I click on this button, I call my bean method which updates two booleans. Depending on those two variables, I show-up different dialog. 
 
Here is my code:

```
    <p:commandButton action="myBean.method" oncomplete="
    if (#{myBean.var1}) {  
        PF('dialog1').show() 
    } else { 
        if (#{myBean.var2}) { 
            PF('dialog2').show() 
        } else { 
            PF('dialog3').show() 
        }
   }" />
```

With this, oncomplete event gets always the initial value of my bean variables and not the updated ones :( 
 And I don't know if it is the best way to do it ;)

Comment: The answer by Fritz is correct. The 'oncomplete' javascript (in fact the whole commandButton) is only updated when you, well... update it... via an ajax call. This simply cannot be (easily) done otherwise since it is all client-side. You just cannot update something in a component during a call it is making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use RequestContext utility of Primefaces? With it you can just put the logic of whether to open which dialog.

```
public void method(){
  RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  if (var1) {  
     requestContext.update("PF('dialog1').show()");
  } else { 
  if (var2) { 
     requestContext.update("PF('dialog2').show()");
  } else { 
     requestContext.update("PF('dialog3').show()");
  }
}
```

Or if you really want to have your logic in javascript you can also use the `addCallbackParam()`

**Callback Parameters** (quoting from Primefaces User Guide 6.0)

*There may be cases where you need values from backing beans in ajax callbacks. Callback
parameters are serialized to JSON and provided as an argument in ajax callbacks for this.*

HTML:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.validate}"
oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
```

BEAN:

```
public void validate() {
//isValid = calculate isValid
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.addCallbackParam("isValid", true or false);
}
```

isValid parameter will be available in handleComplete callback as;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {
var isValid = args.isValid;
}
</script>
```